# Filtering for multiple df columns where any of column or none are = value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df as below:

```
ID | Night_Shift | Day_Shift | Weekend_Shift | Morning_Shift
3       True         False         False          True
1       False        False         False          False
2       True         True          False          True
```

How Can I create new column that says True if there is at least 1 True in any of the Shift Column or False if all are False?

Expected Output:

```
ID | Night_Shift | Day_Shift | Weekend_Shift | Morning_Shift | New_Col
    3       True         False         True          True        True
    1       False        False         False          False       False
    2       True         False         False          False       True
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col_1': [True, True, False, False], 'col_2': [True, False, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['result'] = df['col_1'] | df['col_2']
print (df)
```

in your code

```
df['New_Col'] = df['Night_Shift'] | df['Day_Shift'] | df['Weekend_Shift'] | df['Morning_Shift']
```

Comment: This gives False for all False too?

Comment: Your data is different than mine

Answer (score 2):

Check with `any`

```
df['New'] = df.drop('ID', axis = 1).any(axis = 1)
```

Update

```
df['New'] = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.endswith('_Shift')].any(1)
```

Comment: I have multiple other columns in my df besides ID I only showed just ID in sample set, is there a different method? Do you agree with other answer?

Comment: @Chris90 I still think any is better

Comment: Just use the or "|" operator between all columns. Like df['New_Col'] = df['Night_Shift'] | df['Day_Shift'] | df['Weekend_Shift'] | df['Morning_Shift']